# NestJS + prisma property from prisma.schema does not exist on type PrismaService

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma

I am trying to create a simple backend with Postgres, nestjs and prisma as described [here](https://www.prisma.io/blog/nestjs-prisma-rest-api-7D056s1BmOL0#development-environment). to my knowledge I have not deviated from this tutorial.
I used `npx nest generate resource` to generate a resource called users. I am now in Users.service.ts and am getting this error.

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService){}
  create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return 'This action adds a new user';
  }

  findAll() {
    // return `This action returns all users`;
    return this.prisma.user.findMany({ where: { name: "tedward bundy"}})
  }
  // error here - src/users/users.service.ts:15:24 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
return this.prisma.user.findMany({ where: { name: "tedward bundy"}})
```

here is the schema.prisma

```
generator client {


provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String  
  email    String @unique
  address   String?
  phoneNumber String?  
  password String?

  Cart Cart[]
}

model Cart {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  cartNumber    Int @unique
  userId Int     @unique
  productId Int     @unique

  User User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  Product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
}

model Product {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String?
  cost   Int
  count Int
  Cart Cart[]
}
```

I have also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274503/property-does-not-exist-when-i-want-to-use-model-added-in-prisma-schema) at previous questions. I have run both commands multiple times and then closed and reopened vscode but with no luck. here is a GitHub link in case you need the rest of the project.
https://github.com/amustafa15/backend-ameenazon

so the desired outcome is for prisma to recognize the type user exists on type PrismaService. I have tried to generate resources for the other models in schema.prisma and all with the same result. so how do I get prisma to recognize "user"? I am using prisma 5.1.0 and @prisma/client 4.16.2. the tutorial said the generated resource name should be plural

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I forgot to update prisma.module.ts and prisma.service.ts. using the code in the tutorial solved that.